# calls to static member variable causes LNK2001 in DLL

Tags: c++, variables, dll, static

Im testing a DLL library I'm writing and after trying to compile it, I get a LNK2001 error for a static variable within a class.
FooApi.h

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #ifdef FOO_DLL
        #define FOO_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define FOO_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define FOO_API
#endif
```

Bar.h

```
        class FOO_API Bar
        {
        private:            
            static bool mIsActive;
        };
```

and in Bar.cpp:

```
bool FOO_API Bar::mIsActive = false;
```

Upon building a test project using the DLL, I get an LNK2001 unresolved external symbol. Any ideas on how to resolve this? Sidenote: none of my static functions within the same class has this issue.

**Error:**

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool
>   vkdebug::Bar::mIsActive" (?mIsActive@Bar@vkdebug@2_NA)

Comment: I guess you need to use `FOO_API` (whatever that is) on the definition of `Bar:mIsActive` (in the .cpp) file as well as on the class declaration.

Comment: Quote the **exact** linker error message.

Comment: if FOO_DLL defined? I suggest to remove FOO_DLL and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added the exact error.

Comment: Wrong symbol, it should be looking for the `__imp` version of this variable.  Or in other words, it is not declared dllimport.  The FOO_DLL macro is also defined in your test project.  Bad.